# Javascript window tree recursion and infinite objects

Tags: javascript, recursion, infinite-loop

I'm trying to write a function that will dump a recursive tree of `window` for all browsers. A problem that I immediately realized I was going to have, had to do with infinite objects (`window.window.window.window`). Just for laughs, I tried it anyways, and I got an error as I expected. `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` (testing in Chrome)

So the first approach to check against objects that were going to cause this was simply:

```
if (variable != 'window' && variable != 'top' && variable != 'self' && variable != 'frames')
```

I'm thinking maybe that would have worked, and I simply missed a couple. It was a good theory, but I still get the maximum stack error. So I decided to type `window` in Chrome's console, and manually look for all of the `[DOMWindow]` types, to add to this list. While doing that, I noticed the `Infinity: Infinity` value, which brought me to my next approach:

```
if (typeof namespace[variable]['Infinity'] === 'undefined')
```

I still got the maximum stack error with that, so I did a bit of Google searching, and learned about `isFinite`, so now I have: (edit: actually I just realized `isFinite` isn't what I thought it was)

```
if (isFinite(tree[variable]))
```

The error finally went away, but the problem with this approach is that all objects in `window` are returning false for this, so the recursion fails. I realize that some of the approaches probably aren't even cross-browser compatible, but it would be nice if I could get it to at least work in one browser in the mean time.

So how can I check for objects that are going to cause an infinite loop?

Here's my code, just for anyone who might be interested:

```
(function () {
    window.onload = function () {
        window.onload = ''; // don't want to get our own code
        console.log((function (namespace) {
            tree = {};
            for (var variable in namespace) {
                /* gonna need these later
                var variable_typeof = typeof namespace[variable],
                    variable_object_tostring = Object.prototype.toString(namespace[variable]);
                */

                //if (variable != 'window' && variable != 'top' && variable != 'self' && variable != 'frames')
                //if (typeof namespace[variable]['Infinity'] === 'undefined')
                if (isFinite(tree[variable]))
                    tree[variable] = arguments.callee(namespace[variable]);
                else tree[variable] = 'Infinity';
            }
            return tree;
        })(window)); // Start from root
    }
})();
```

**Update:**
Here is a working product of what I finally came up with, for anyone interested.
[GGG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886931/ggg) is worthy of mention for his help.

```
function loop (namespace) {
    if (namespace['__infinite_test']) return '[[recursion]]'; // It's infinite
    namespace['__infinite_test'] = true; // Note that we've been through this object
    var tree = {};
    for (var variable in namespace) {
        try { // For an issue in Chrome throwing an error
            namespace[variable]['__tester'] = null;
            delete namespace[variable]['__tester'];
        }
        catch (e) {
            tree[variable] = namespace[variable];
            continue;
        }
        if (namespace.propertyIsEnumerable(variable)) tree[variable] = loop(namespace[variable]);
        else tree[variable] = namespace[variable];
    }
    return tree;
}
console.log(loop(window));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to prevent infinite recursion in your problem is to keep track of a list of all objects you have already visited and if you encounter an object you've already visited, you don't recurse into it.

When you encounter an object that is not in your list, you add it to your list and then recurse into it.

Comment: I actually tried that as well, but it resulted in an incomplete list. I might resort to this, and find some way to elaborate it. Maybe I can make a separate function to run one more level, and add just the missing elements. Gonna have to brainstorm on this.

Comment: @andrewjackson - I suspect there was a flaw in your implementation then.  Share the code you tried and we can comment on it.

Comment: I've scrapped it, I'll have to rewrite it. It was actually the first thing I tried, even before my so called "first approach". I'll rewrite it now, update with it, and let you know what I have.

Comment: Actually, you're right. I should have just stuck to the original plan, I've had a great idea to implement this, that I think it going to work out great. I'll post the code when done if anyone is interested. I guess I was just hoping for something more simple, but I don't mind complexity.